# Name of CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture is "vi-US"

Tags: culture

I got name of CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture  is "vi-US" when debug in Iphone Pro Max 14 simulator. And also not found in list of culture codes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

[image]

What's wrong with my code or device? Anybody help me what this? Thanks